# Unable to send POST json request to REST Web service through AJAX

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, rest

Problem: I am trying to send an ajax post request to a Rest Web Service on remote server which produces a JSON response.

While testing with Advanced Rest Client, and cURL for the similar url and post data, I am getting the required response, **But If I try to send the same request through jquery, the request gives `HTTP 400 Status Code (The request sent by client was syntactically incorrect)`.** It happens for GET as well as POST.

Here is the jquery Function:

```
$.support.cors = true; 
    $.ajax({     
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost:8089/myschool/rest/report/firstrequest/json',
     data:'{"studentList":[{"name":"Abhi","marks":"23"}], "classGID":"9de6f363-cb53-4845-ab7e-1e7c8bc7b33b","subjectGID":"1fd61614-5027-4daf-ac52-33c18cc86afd","School":"LKSEC"}',  
   dataType:"json",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   cache:"false",
   async:"true",
   processdata:"false",
   success: function(html)
    {
        ss=html; 
        console.log(ss);
    },
   error:function(error)
   {
    console.log(error.status)
   },
   complete:function(html){
   console.log()
   }
        });
```

Here is the cURL:

```
    curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d '{"studentList":[{"name":"Abhi","marks":"23"}], "classGID":"9de6f363-cb53-4845-ab7e-1e7c8bc7b33b","subjectGID":"1fd61614-5027-4daf-ac52-33c18cc86afd","School":"LKSEC"}' 
http://localhost:8089/myschool/rest/report/firstrequest/json
```

Comment: I think instead of passing data as string you can look into the `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: I tried but that also didn't work.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747373/how-to-pass-multi-dimensional-array-with-jquery-ajax-post) it might help for the syntactical error specially for multi-array data pass.