# How to send array of arrays as data in $.ajax()?

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

I know this question has been asked before many times but none of them helped me.
I am trying to **pass an array of arrays**(which may or may not have arrays in themselves) through data using $.ajax(). The response received from the server should be the same as data sent (acc to the code in php) but it sends blank object.
Please help me knowing the correct syntax of passing such an array.

val_pass is an array of arrays and #display_message is paragraph to append on. Here goes my code:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://someurl.com/',
        // data: JSON.stringify(val_pass),
        // data: JSON.stringify({paramName: val_pass}),
        // data: {'myArray': val_pass},
        // data: $.toJSON(val_pass),
        data: {val_pass: val_pass},
        // data: $.serialize(val_pass),
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            $('#display_message').append('Data successfully passed');
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown){
            console.log(xhr+status+errorThrown);
            alert("Sorry");
        },
    });
```

PS: commented lines are various ways i tried to pass an array. I am new to ajax please ignore my noobness.

Comment: can you add your relevant php-code too ?

Comment: What is the problem? Use JSON.stringify: `JSON.stringify([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])` => "[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]". I think you need more attention to your php code, to parse a response as a array of arrays.

Comment: i tried using this by seeing similar questions and answers and it worked for this simple array
var info = [];
info[0] = 'hi';
info[1] = 'hello';


$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {info:info},
   url: "index.php",
});

Comment: Use the `JQuery.parseJSON(str)` function to convert the string returned by `JSON.stringify` into an actual javascript object, then set the object as the data property in your ajax call and set dataType to json

Comment: Eg: `$.parseJSON('{ "0" : "1,2,3", "1" : "4,5,6" }')`

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747373/how-to-pass-multi-dimensional-array-with-jquery-ajax-post?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the solution for the problem.
Firstly instead of passing arrays of arrays, I sent it as an array of objects.

Now my val_pass is array of objects.Code:

```
var jObject={};
jObject = JSON.stringify(val_pass);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST';
    data: {jObject: jObject};
    url: some_url;
});
```

http://pavanarya.wordpress.com/2012/09/09/calling-a-webservice-using-jquery-and-passing-jsonarray-object/

referred this link for help.

Comment: And how did you handle this in PHP in the receiving page?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Json then type should be json. And the function parameter for success namely json is the variable that holds the data. So data: json

```
 $.ajax({
 url: url_to_load,
 dataType: 'json',
 data: json,
 success: function(json){
 };
 });
```

A more user friendly version is as follows:

```
$.getJson("service.php",function(json){
//code goes here
});
```

Comment: a more user friendly? You gotta be kidding